# Writing computer generated music to a wav.file in C - follow-up 2

Tags: c, file, audio, music

See the [previous iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105341/writing-computer-generated-music-to-a-wav-file-in-c-follow-up).

**What's new**: endianness is now handled more gracefully (only one endianness check, and convertion if need be) and music is more funky.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/****************************************************
* From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791864/ *
*      c-program-to-check-little-vs-big-endian      *
****************************************************/
static bool is_little_endian() 
{
    volatile uint32_t i = 0x01234567;
    return (*((uint8_t*)(&i))) == 0x67;
}

static uint16_t little_endian_uint16_t(uint16_t num) 
{
    return (((0xff00 & num) >> 8) | ((0xff & num) << 8));
}

static uint32_t little_endian_uint32_t(uint32_t num) {
    return ((((0xff000000 & num) >> 24) | 
             ((0xff & num) << 24)       | 
             ((0xff0000 & num) >> 8))   | 
             ((0xff00 & num) << 8));
}

#pragma pack(0)
typedef struct {

    /***************
    * RIFF header. *
    ***************/
    char fChunkID[4];
    uint32_t fChunkSize;
    char fFormat[4];

    /******************
    * "fmt" subchunk. *
    ******************/
    char fSubchunk1ID[4];
    uint32_t fSubchunk1Size;
    uint16_t fAudioFormat;
    uint16_t fNumChannels;
    uint32_t fSampleRate;
    uint32_t fByteRate;
    uint16_t fBlockAlign;
    uint16_t fBitsPerSample;

    /*******************
    * "data" subchunk. *
    *******************/
    char fSubchunk2ID[4];
    uint32_t fSubchunk2Size;
} file_format_header;


bool WriteWavePCM(uint16_t* sound, size_t pairAmount, const char* fileName)
{
    if (sound == NULL || fileName == NULL) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    FILE* fout = fopen(fileName, "wb");

    if (fout == NULL) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    /******************************
    *  Magic file format strings. *
    ******************************/
    static const char fChunkID[]     = {'R', 'I', 'F', 'F'};
    static const char fFormat[]      = {'W', 'A', 'V', 'E'};
    static const char fSubchunk1ID[] = {'f', 'm', 't', ' '};
    static const char fSubchunk2ID[] = {'d', 'a', 't', 'a'};

    /*****************************************************************
    * Can't make the following local static, as we need to check the *
    * endianness.                                                    *
    *****************************************************************/
    static const uint16_t N_CHANNELS                   = 2;
    static const uint32_t fSubchunk1Size               = 16;
    static const uint16_t fAudioFormat                 = 1;
    static const uint16_t fBitsPerSample               = 16;
    static const uint32_t fRIFFChunkDescriptorLength   = 12;
    static const uint32_t fFmtSubChunkDescriptorLength = 24;

    file_format_header hdr;

    /**************************************
    * Load the magic file format strings. *
    **************************************/
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
    {
        hdr.fChunkID[i]     = fChunkID[i];
        hdr.fFormat[i]      = fFormat[i];
        hdr.fSubchunk1ID[i] = fSubchunk1ID[i];
        hdr.fSubchunk2ID[i] = fSubchunk2ID[i];
    }

    /********************************
    * WriteWavePCM() configuration: *
    * - 2 channels,                 *
    * - frequency 44100 Hz.         *
    ********************************/
    static const uint32_t SAMPLE_RATE   = 44100;
    static const uint16_t BITS_PER_BYTE = 8;

    const uint32_t fByteRate = SAMPLE_RATE * N_CHANNELS * fBitsPerSample / 
                               BITS_PER_BYTE;

    const uint16_t fBlockAlign = N_CHANNELS * fBitsPerSample / BITS_PER_BYTE;

    const uint32_t fSubchunk2Size = pairAmount * N_CHANNELS * fBitsPerSample / 
                                    BITS_PER_BYTE;

    const uint32_t fChunkSize = fRIFFChunkDescriptorLength + 
                                fFmtSubChunkDescriptorLength + fSubchunk2Size;

    hdr.fAudioFormat   = fAudioFormat;
    hdr.fBitsPerSample = fBitsPerSample;
    hdr.fBlockAlign    = fBlockAlign;
    hdr.fByteRate      = fByteRate;
    hdr.fChunkSize     = fChunkSize;
    hdr.fNumChannels   = N_CHANNELS;
    hdr.fSampleRate    = SAMPLE_RATE;
    hdr.fSubchunk1Size = fSubchunk1Size;
    hdr.fSubchunk2Size = fSubchunk2Size;

    bool little_endian = is_little_endian();

    if (!little_endian) 
    {
        hdr.fAudioFormat   = little_endian_uint16_t(hdr.fAudioFormat);
        hdr.fBitsPerSample = little_endian_uint16_t(hdr.fBitsPerSample);
        hdr.fBlockAlign    = little_endian_uint16_t(hdr.fBlockAlign);
        hdr.fByteRate      = little_endian_uint32_t(hdr.fByteRate);
        hdr.fChunkSize     = little_endian_uint32_t(hdr.fChunkSize);
        hdr.fNumChannels   = little_endian_uint16_t(hdr.fNumChannels);
        hdr.fSampleRate    = little_endian_uint32_t(hdr.fSampleRate);
        hdr.fSubchunk1Size = little_endian_uint32_t(hdr.fSubchunk1Size);
        hdr.fSubchunk2Size = little_endian_uint32_t(hdr.fSubchunk2Size);
    }

    /******************************** 
    * Write the file format header. *
    ********************************/
    size_t ws = fwrite(&hdr, sizeof(hdr), 1, fout);

    if (ws != 1) 
    {
        fclose(fout);
        return false;
    }

    if (!little_endian) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pairAmount * N_CHANNELS; ++i) 
        {
            sound[i] = little_endian_uint16_t(sound[i]);
        }
    }

    /************************ 
    * Write the sound data. *
    ************************/
    ws = fwrite(sound, sizeof(uint16_t), pairAmount * N_CHANNELS, fout);
    fclose(fout);
    return ws == pairAmount * N_CHANNELS;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    /************************************
    * Around 23 seconds of pure techno! *
    ************************************/
    static const unsigned int N_SAMPLE_PAIRS = 1048576;

    uint16_t N_CHANNELS = little_endian_uint16_t(2);
    uint16_t* sound = malloc(sizeof(uint16_t) * N_SAMPLE_PAIRS * N_CHANNELS);

    if (!sound)
    {
        puts("Could not allocate space for the sound data.");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    uint16_t j;

    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < N_SAMPLE_PAIRS * N_CHANNELS; i += 2, j++)
    {
        uint16_t datum1 = 450 * ((j >> 9 | j >> 7 | j >> 2) % 128);
        uint16_t datum2 = 450 * ((j >> 11 | j >> 8 | (j >> 3)^(j << 1) ) % 128);

        sound[i]     = datum1; /* One channel.     */
        sound[i + 1] = datum2; /* Another channel. */
    }

    const char* file_name = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "Default.wav";
    bool status = WriteWavePCM(sound, N_SAMPLE_PAIRS, file_name);
    free(sound);

    if (status)
    {
        printf("Discotheque is ready in \"%s\"\n", file_name);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Something seems to have gone wrong.");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it confusing that the header data sometimes contains the data in little-endian and sometimes in native-endian format. To avoid this, I would rather define:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t a, b, c, d;
} uint32_le;

void uint32_le_set(uint32_le *var, uint32_t value) { ... }

uint32_t uint32_le_get(const uint32_le *var) { return ...; }
```

That way you cannot confuse the two representations. Plus, you don't need any code that relies on `volatile` or low-level memory manipulation.

Comment: "native-endian"? Like the folks that like to say "Hao!"? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

1. There is one conceptional behavior I personally don't like: The code will leave a partially written file behind in case of an error, instead of removing it.
2. ```
   uint16_t N_CHANNELS = little_endian_uint16_t(2);
   sizeof(uint16_t) * N_SAMPLE_PAIRS * N_CHANNELS
   ```

   `N_CHANNELS` is not guaranteed to contain the value `2`.

Comment: Yeah the line here uint16_t N_CHANNELS = little_endian_uint16_t(2); <-- confusingly allocates > 1 GB instead of just 8 MB or whatever. Very confusing.